# How to display values on line stacked columns on highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, react-highcharts

[image]

I want to display the value on the growth in the stacked column but it hasn't worked yet, can anyone help me? ;(

I set it on the datalabel like it still doesn't work

```
 plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        dataLabels: {
                  enabled: true,
                  formatter: function() {    
                        return this.point.y;
                   },
                  style:{
                        fontSize: 8
                    }
              }
    },
    line: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            allowOverlap: true
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ndhanajh06/r16e2Lyw/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `spline` series type, so you need to enable data labels for `spline`, not `line`:

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    ...
  },
  spline: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      allowOverlap: true
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fputh18a/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.spline.dataLabels

Comment: Thank you sir, I guess using the line. ;) hhi